# 3 posts independent but related. Seo solutions

Tags: seo, title

I have 3 blog posts that want to go deep in a subject. Each one covers a different aspect. Each one can be read independently. At the same time, they are connected.

I thought that I could do different thinks:

1- Make absolute different titles and subtitles. Just put a link at the end of the post with a note saying something like: this is a part of a series of articles about the subject xxx.

2- A second option would be to make a title with the big subject that is common with the 3 posts. Then a subtitle different in each post. I would add the links at the end of the post, like in the option num. 1.

```
<h1>Big subject. Part 1<h1>
<h2>A unique subtitle for each post<h2>
```

3- A third option would be to make the title different in each post. Then a subtitle that makes the connection with the big subject. I add the links at the end too.

```
<h1>A unique title for each post<h1>
<h2>Big subject. Part 1<h2>
```

- What is the best option from a SEO perspective?
- Is there any other better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you write them as 3 indepentent stories and (in the beginning) pretend the other 2 don't exists. That gives you an answer for your H1/H2 problem, because you now create relevant titles for the stories. The H1 title is intended for the title of the page and has to be unique and descriptive for a user. By giving it the title of the story, you comply.

Now you have 3 stories, you can optimize:

- Create internal links between the articles. This is the main task as it has the most benefit
- Improve the content itself, make sure it reads well for your audiance
- Evaluate the titles, can you reword it so that the titles are connected (without repeat yourself)?
- You can now create a tiny navigation/menu between the stories. You can do this like a menu, of some nevigation bar, or by adding a "Like this? Also read ...." at the bottom of a story.