# Connecting multi-part blog post series for SEO purposes

Tags: seo, blog, pagination

I remember reading about a technique at some point to connect **multi-part pages or blog posts** to indicate to the search engine that this is actually part of one article.

I can't however remember the terminology so I can't find anything on the web.

This [question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/98798/3-posts-independent-but-related-seo-solutions) is somewhat similar but doesn't seem to have the answer I'm looking for.

I thought this might have something to do with **pagination**, but can't find anything on that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the rel next, rel previous HTML attributes: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en

From the source link above, here is the generic example:

```
http://www.example.com/article-part1.html
http://www.example.com/article-part2.html
http://www.example.com/article-part3.html
http://www.example.com/article-part4.html
```

In the  section of the first page (http://www.example.com/article-part1.html), add a link tag pointing to the next page in the sequence, like this:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article-part2.html">
```

Because this is the first URL in the sequence, there’s no need to add markup for rel="prev".

On the second and third pages, add links pointing to the previous and next URLs in the sequence. For example, you could add the following to the second page of the sequence:

```
<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article-part1.html">
<link rel="next" href="http://www.example.com/article-part3.html">
```

When developing, one of the most common development mistakes is to not end the rel next attribute on the final item in the cluster. For example, if your 5 part article ends at /article-part5, ensure you do not include a rel next to /article-part6. Seems obvious, but it's a common oversight - the real problem occurs when the server /article-part6 returns "something' with a 200 response code, which also contains a rel next directive. That means these rel next links to "fake" pages get crawled, indexed and bloat your site, add overhead for crawlers and create unnecessary duplication.

Comment: thanks that's what I was looking for. I'm working on a Wordpress site, just wish I knew how to add these link elements to Wordpress.

Comment: If you use Yoast SEO plugin, it will automatically add rel next/prev to Wordpress default pagination.

Comment: how would Yoast know that the posts are linked?

Comment: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/is-the-plugin-compatible-with-paginated-content/